# Postman shows a CSRF error when using the Rossum API

Tags: http, postman, csrf

When using the [Rossum API for data capture](https://api.elis.rossum.ai/docs/) with Postman, I'm getting this error for any HTTP request after a login:

```
{
  "detail": "CSRF Failed: Referer checking failed - no Referer.",
  "code": "permission_denied"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the Rossum API is Django-based and uses special cookies to prevent CSRF attacks, issued during the /login call. The CSRF cookie guard prevents from third-party websites wrongly issuing calls through a logged-in user browser - the cookie must be set in combination with a correct referer setting to verify that the call is not issued by a third-party website.

However, Postman is using the cookie but not setting a referer properly. Clearing the cookies in Postman resolves the issue.

This is also why the issue does not appear while using `curl` or HTML5 fetch.